# Change font-family of title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change `font-family` of the `title` attribute on my input field using JavaScript Or jQuery. Is there a way of doing this?

```
<input type="text" title="Enter Your Name" id="txtName" />
```

Comment: Define a css class with the font-family and toggleClass in jQuery.
`$('#txtName').toggleClass('myFontFamily')`

Comment: You cannot change the font which the `title` attribute is displayed in (presuming you mean the tooltip which appears when the element is hovered over). If you want this behaviour you will need to implement a tooltip library and style it as required.

Comment: @TimVermaelen note that the OP wants to style the `title` attribute text, not the text of the element itself.

Comment: Wonder why it's downvoted, seems like an interesting question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original `title` attribute styles (on `<a>`, `<img>` or `<input>`) are defined by the operating system you use - same like, for example, `<select>`.

What's possible is to replace default tooltips with in-flight created HTML, using CSS and JS.

For that, you can use some open sourced libraries, like for example [Bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#examples):

```js
$('input').tooltip()
```

```css
.tooltip {
  font-family: 'Unlock', cursive!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unlock" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter Your Name" id="txtName" />
```